# TableViewController doesn't show content

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building an app and I am having some trouble with a table view with static cells. I used a TableViewController in the MainStoryBoard, and designed a some static cells, with a label and text field. However when I connect actions to my TableViewController file, the content does not display.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried ? You should provide some code so we can help you... Check numberOfItemsInSection - what do you get there? Do your cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called? Etc...

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:
as the comment by Miknash stated check that cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called

Check that numberOfSectionsInTable and numberOfRowsInSection is called. Check if you've set the itemCount to a specific value in the interface builder.

Also, one that always gets me is make sure you specified your delegate and datasource to the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set delegate and dataSource of tableView ?

try this:

```
func setupTableView() {
   tableView.dataSource = self
   tableView.delegate = self
}
```

call this method in `viewDidLoad()`